# Como Typar um objeto em typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Esse objeto depois de typado está saindo nulo. Não estou conseguindo consumir os dados:

```
type FirebaseQuestions = Record<string, {
    author: {
      name: string;
      avatar: string;
    }
    content: string;
    isAnswered: boolean;
    isHighlighted: boolean;
}>
```

E a tipagem está assim:

```
const databaseRoom = room.val();

const firebaseQuestion: FirebaseQuestions = databaseRoom.question ?? {};

console.log(firebaseQuestion);

const parsedQuestions = Object.entries(firebaseQuestion).map(([key, value]) => {
    return{
        id: key,
        content: value.content,
        author: value.author,
        isHighlighted: value.isHighlighted,
        isAnswered: value.isAnswered,
    }
    console.log(databaseRoom.question);
})

console.log(parsedQuestions);
```

Nenhum dos `console.log()` mostra algum tipo de dado.

Comment: Se o valor está nulo, então foi cadastrado como nulo no banco. Verifique os valores salvos pelo console do Firebase

Comment: Massa vou verificar

Comment: Na verdade acabei de achar o erro ;-; Na tipagem eu coloquei *quenstions* e na atribuição do tipo usei question.